# Java email parser

Tags: java, parsing, email

I have to parse the email message like this and figure out the body,date etc.Any help would be appreciated.

```
Date:        XXXXX
Reply-To:     XXXXX
Sender:       XXXXX
From:        XXXX
Subject:     Test
In-Reply-To:  XXXX
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=__Part416ABDAE.0__="
=__Part416ABDAE.0__=
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Test
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please show how far you've got and where you're running into problems. If not, is there any reason you're not using an existing library?

Comment: Google for Java Mail API... unless this is homework and you have to write a parser... in which case please tag this correctly.

Comment: I have those email messages in file (txt) format extracted from mail server.So would java mail API work there? Also it has html also inside that

Answer (score 2):

Here's a regex solution:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "Date:        XXXXX\n"
                     + "Reply-To:     XXXXX\n"
                     + "Sender:       XXXXX\n"
                     + "From:        XXXX\n"
                     + "Subject:     Test\n"
                     + "In-Reply-To:  XXXX\n"
                     + "Mime-Version: 1.0\n"
                     + "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; " +
                                 "boundary=\"=__Part416ABDAE.0__=\"";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?):\\s+(.*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + m.group(1));
            System.out.println("Val: " + m.group(2));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Key: Date
Val: XXXXX

Key: Reply-To
Val: XXXXX

Key: Sender
Val: XXXXX

Key: From
Val: XXXX

Key: Subject
Val: Test

Key: In-Reply-To
Val: XXXX

Key: Mime-Version
Val: 1.0

Key: Content-Type
Val: multipart/alternative; boundary="=__Part416ABDAE.0__="
```

Comment: thanks for the solution.Actually I am looking for is I have email extracts in a text file format and I have to run parser for those.It has also some messages in html format.

Comment: if you edit your question and elaborate I might be able to elaborate my answer.

Comment: Use a `new Scanner(new File("your_file.txt"))` and do `Matcher m = p.matcher(scanner.nextLine())` inside the loop. (And go on until `!scanner.hasNext`. Let me know if you need further instructions.

Comment: Thanks .I m trying to paste the content but this is not taking.Is there any way I can attach file to it?

Comment: No. Use paste-bin if you like.

Comment: It has some html also in the body where I am finding it tough to parse .Still I am not able to paste it .

Answer (score 0):

If your serious about parsing email (and this is not a home work parsing assignment) you should look at **[Mime4J](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/)**.